# How to check group membership for a process that is not "self"?

Tags: c++, winapi, uac, administrator

I'm trying to use [this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389(v=vs.85).aspx) to check security group membership for an arbitrary process that I have a handle for. But in my code below `CheckTokenMembership` fails with error code 1309, or `ERROR_NO_IMPERSONATION_TOKEN`. I'm not sure I understand how I can get that impersonation token...

So what am I doing wrong here?

```
void check_membership(HANDLE hProc)
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    if(OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        check_group_membership(hToken, L"Local Group", DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_USERS);
        check_group_membership(hToken, L"Admin Group", DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS);
        check_group_membership(hToken, L"Domain Admin Group", DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_ADMINS);
        check_group_membership(hToken, L"Schema Admin Group", DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_SCHEMA_ADMINS);
        check_group_membership(hToken, L"Enterprise Admin Group", DOMAIN_GROUP_RID_ENTERPRISE_ADMINS);

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
}


void check_group_membership(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR pStrName, DWORD nSubauthority)
{
    BOOL bIsMember;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY NtAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;

    wprintf(L"Local %s: ", pStrName);

    PSID pSID = NULL; 
    if(AllocateAndInitializeSid(&NtAuthority, 2,
        SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
        nSubauthority,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pSID))
    {
        bIsMember = FALSE;
        if(CheckTokenMembership(hToken, pSID, &bIsMember))
        {
            wprintf(L"%s", bIsMember ? L"Yes" : L"No");
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"<CheckErr: (%d)>", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"<SidErr: (%d)>", GetLastError());
    }

    wprintf(L"\n");

    if(pSID)
    {
        FreeSid(pSID) == NULL);
        pSID = NULL;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN does confirm that it is a requirement:

> The token must be an impersonation token.

It also says for the NULL handle case:

> `CheckTokenMembership` uses the impersonation token of the calling thread. If the thread is not impersonating, the function duplicates the thread's primary token to create an impersonation token.

You could try this:

```
HANDLE hImpToken;
if (DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_QUERY, NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenImpersonation, &hImpToken))
{
    CheckTokenMembership(hImpToken, ...);
    CloseHandle(hImpToken);
}
```

Comment: Note: Your original input token needs to be opened with TOKEN_DUPLICATE.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although I just noticed the following at the bottom of the `CheckTokenMembership` page: `"Even if a SID is present in the token, the system may not use the SID in an access check. The SID may be disabled or have the SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY attribute. The system uses only enabled SIDs to grant access when performing an access check"` Does it mean that `CheckTokenMembership` may return unreliable results?

Comment: I think they just mean that a disabled or deny-only SID will not grant access and CheckTokenMembership isMember is false for those. Compare this with the old NT4 style method where you check each SID in the token yourself. Deny-only SIDs are Win2000+ and NT4 style gives the wrong result.